# Rewrite Condition partial match causing problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

I have the following rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` file on the root of an ExpressionEngine site to remove the `index.php` portion of the URL...

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(resources|media|images|js|css|fonts|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Which works fine.

However the client now wants a page called "Media Centre" with the URL `www.domain.com/media-centre` which is being ignored because "media" is triggering a match in the rewrite condition.

How do I tell it to ignore "media" but not "media-centre"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe add a `$` at the end?

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(resources|media|images|js|css|fonts|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php)$ [NC]
```

Or maybe just explicity allow "media-center":

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(media-centre) [OR]
RewriteCond $1 !^(resources|media|images|js|css|fonts|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
```

Comment: No, that makes it go recursive constantly adding `index.php` until it falls over

Comment: Thanks Manish that's exactly the logic I was trying to write, I just couldn't work out the syntax. It's currently working fine.

Comment: The cond is stopping resource subdirs, etc, being mapped to index.php so why not `!^(resources/|media/|images/`...

Comment: @TerryE why is it the obvious can be so hard to spot?! That works well too. Thanks for the alternative solution.